# Nested Python for loop only works with the last item in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, input, split

I have encountered an issue where the 2nd for loop in a nested loop in Python only works for the last item in the list.

```
input = input("Words: ")
print(input)
list = input.split('[:,\s]')
print(list)

for each in list:
    for i, item in enumerate(list):
        joined = each + "TEST"
        print(joined)
```

As you can see in the code I am trying to loop through every item in the list and then in each loop of the loop before I want to append the string "TEST" to the end of the word that's currently looped through first loop.

Let's parse an input for example `"aword, anotherword, yetanotherword, certainword"`. I would expect the program to produce the following output `"awordTEST, anotherwordTEST, yetanotherwordTEST, certainwordTEST"`.

Instead this is the actual output `"aword, anotherword, yetanotherword, certainwordTEST"`.

I can't figure out why does the 2nd loop only work for the last item in the list.

Edit: suggested solution was to use a single for loop. The thing is that I need to work with that 2nd for loop later and it is important for it to be in that 2nd for loop. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=input%20%3D%20'aword,%20anotherword,%20yetanotherword,%20certainword'%0Aprint%28input%29%0Alist%20%3D%20input.split%28'%5B%3A,%5Cs%5D'%29%0Aprint%28list%29%0A%0Afor%20each%20in%20list%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i,%20item%20in%20enumerate%28list%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20joined%20%3D%20each%20%2B%20%22TEST%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28joined%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: Side-note: Don't use `list` or `input` as variable names; from the moment you assigned to them, you lost access to the `input` function and the `list` constructor.

Comment: Response to edit: You're welcome to do what you want when you're writing your full code, but that inner loop (that does nothing but multiply the outputs) is not relevant to your question, and as such, shouldn't be part of the [MCVE].

Comment: Hmm I didn't notice since the values were assigned and these functions weren't used later. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @541daw35d: Yeah, in this case, it worked (it just blocked access to the built-ins after the line they got name-shadowed on). Had you done it inside a function, it wouldn't have worked at all (`input = input("Words: ")` would die with `UnboundLocalError`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.split` does not accept regular expressions to split on. If you look at the contents of `list`, you'll see it's just the original string. If you want to split on a regex, you must use [the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```python
import re

inp = input("Words: ")
print(inp)
lst = re.split(r'[:,\s]+', inp)
print(lst)

for each in lst:
    joined = each + "TEST"
    print(joined)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwDIbveYrQy1Y2vHgbePQJHOygHsoWWWW2JY3Inr62Gx7MIfDn@xISVpm9O6ZkX8GzIBOAdQFPmPtbajV4nmKHSkNg66QuUMMSJStMhxgWKzVX1669xXtTtWXv5xZLAzw8I5lxzgjLqAPM9fTW0ZSvbKhB1Z8vvdrQvr0LOiXzyT@0aJyXmXgPK8lfHonFWFfCFw)

I removed the inner loop because it was doing nothing but multiplying outputs, and renamed variables to avoid name-shadowing built-ins.

Comment: How could I have not seen this! Now it all makes sense! Stupid me though that "," meant another item in the list... I would mark this as an answer so others wouldn't stop by but SO will let me do that in 7 minutes so we all need to wait...

Answer (score -1):

you need change this section:

```
for each in list:
    for i, item in enumerate(list):
        joined = each + "TEST"
    print(joined)
```

so the result is

```
awordTEST
anotherwordTEST
yetanotherwordTEST
certainwordTEST
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you changed; this reduces duplicated output, but does not fix the OP's problem (only suffixing the last word due to misuse of `str.split`).